# Backslash Character Error in Postgresql Advanced SQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, psql, crosstab

I'm trying to run this query on Postgresql:

```
SELECT city, year, SUM(raindays)
FROM rainfall
GROUP BY city,year 
HAVING SUM(raindays)>120
ORDER BY city
\crosstabview
```

On command, it runs very okay, however, on any JDBC based context, it throws an error: `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"`

The backslash behind *crosstabview* isn't being recognized. How can I overcome this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: what if you double it (the backslash) ?

Comment: Backslash escaping makes no difference @Zyigh

Comment: You need to run that through `psql`

Comment: I created a function with the crosstabview inside, ran it on psql but it gave me the same error, what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`\crosstabview` is a `psql` command, not a postgreSQL one. It is interpreted by the psql client shell as a display formatting directive. You cannot include it in SQL

See the section on 'Meta-Commands' in the [psql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

To get a similar output you would perhaps need to remove the \crosstabview from the command string, and write a loop collecting your query data into a format for display.

Comment: Crosstabview does so much, so I have to rethink the approach altogether?

Comment: pretty much. You could launch psql in a sub process and capture it's output text with the \crosstabview applied I guess.